# my APK is getting "Parse Error"

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-manifest

I get "Parse Error" - there is a problem parsing the package, when trying to run my APK.
I successfully run the application on the emulator, package it using "Export signed.." from menu and using zipalign, everything looks correct. even the zipalign verification. I am using the latest PLUGIN on Eclipse 3.6 Helios, and tried to deploy to HTC Hero & Google Nexus S. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: No, I just uploaded the APK to a Web Server and downloaded it from there, since I need the application to be deployed to others too.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I got that error when my apps `minsdkversion` was higher than my phones android version

Answer (score 0):

Using the export option from the Eclipse plugin will do the zipalign step for you automatically. Try generating it again, don't zipalign it manually and see what you get.